# Performing calculations on properties generically and fast

Tags: c#, loops, generics, properties

The goal is to create a method which generically performs calculations on a property of a list of objects in a performant manner. Below is the entire test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestApp
{
        public class Minute
        {
            public DateTime DateTimeUtc { get; set; }
            public float Source { get; set; }
            public float Mult2 { get; set; }
            public float Mult3 { get; set; }
            public float Mult4 { get; set; }
        }

        class Program
        {
            public static List<Minute> Minutes = new List<Minute>();

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
                {
                    Minute newMinute = new Minute();
                    newMinute.Source = i;
                    Minutes.Add(newMinute);
                }

                GenerateMult2(Minutes, 2); // 160 ms
                GenerateMult2Generic(Minutes, typeof(Minute), nameof(Minute.Source), nameof(Minute.Mult2),2); // 4300 ms
            }

            public static void GenerateMult2(List<Minute> Minutes, int multiplier)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Minutes.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Simplified calculation, there will eventually be a lot more code that goes here!
                    Minutes[i].Mult2 = Minutes[i].Source * multiplier;
                }
            }

            public static void GenerateMult2Generic<T>(List<T> SourceList, Type ContainerType, string propNameSource, string propNameMult, int multiplier)
            {
                var propertyInfoSource = ContainerType.GetProperty(propNameSource);
                var propertyInfoMult = ContainerType.GetProperty(propNameMult);

                foreach (T item in SourceList)
                {
                    float sourceValue = (float)propertyInfoSource.GetValue(item);
                    propertyInfoMult.SetValue(item, sourceValue * multiplier);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this test app there is a method called **GenerateMult2**, whose purpose is to make some calculation on one of the properties in a list of Minute objects. This method works fine and is fast. The problem is that the method is too specific. If I wanted to do the same calculations on the properties Mult3 and Mult4, I would need to make a separate method for each of these properties, which is too much duplicated code. I want to make this method more generic, which is, I want the method to accept lists of other types as well, for example a list of Day objects or Second objects. Furthermore, I want to tell the method which property to perform the calculations on.

So I've made an attempt at creating a generic method called **GenerateMult2Generic**. This method performs the exact same calculation as the GenerateMult2 method, and is multipurpose, which is what I want. The huge disadvantage is that it's way too slow due to the reflections.

How can the GenerateMult2 method be made in a generic fashion, but with a performance penalty of no more than 5%?

**Update with solution**

Having studied the answers here, the best is one that was given by Ed Plunkett, but somehow was removed. Therefore, I'm posting the original code updated with the ideas from that answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class Minute : BaseTime
    {
        public float MovingAverageFast { get; set; }
        public float MovingAverageSlow { get; set; }
        public float RsiFast { get; set; }
        public float RsiSlow { get; set; }
    }

    public class Day : BaseTime
    {
        public float MovingAverageFast { get; set; }
        public float MovingAverageSlow { get; set; }
        public float RsiFast { get; set; }
        public float RsiSlow { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseTime
    {
        public DateTime DateTimeUtc { get; set; }
        public float Source { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static List<Minute> Minutes = new List<Minute>();
        public static List<Day> Days = new List<Day>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Minutes = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).Select(n => new Minute { Source = n }).ToList();
            Days = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).Select(n => new Day { Source = n }).ToList();

            // Generating data for Minutes
            GenerateMovingAverage(Minutes, 100, (m, value) => ((Minute)m).MovingAverageFast = value);
            GenerateMovingAverage(Minutes, 500, (m, value) => ((Minute)m).MovingAverageSlow = value);
            GenerateRsi(Minutes, 60, (m, value) => ((Minute)m).RsiFast = value);
            GenerateRsi(Minutes, 250, (m, value) => ((Minute)m).RsiSlow = value);

            // Generating data for Days
            GenerateMovingAverage(Days, 8, (d, value) => ((Day)d).MovingAverageFast = value);
            GenerateMovingAverage(Days, 45, (d, value) => ((Day)d).MovingAverageSlow = value);
            GenerateRsi(Days, 5, (d, value) => ((Day)d).RsiFast = value);
            GenerateRsi(Days, 21, (d, value) => ((Day)d).RsiSlow = value);
        }

        public static void GenerateMovingAverage(IEnumerable<BaseTime> BaseTimeObjects, int Period, Action<BaseTime, float> setter)
        {
            foreach (var BaseTimeObject in BaseTimeObjects)
            {
                float newValue;
                newValue = BaseTimeObject.Source * Period; // pseudo calculation for generating moving average
                setter(BaseTimeObject, newValue);
            }
        }

        public static void GenerateRsi(IEnumerable<BaseTime> BaseTimeObjects, int Period, Action<BaseTime, float> setter)
        {
            foreach (var BaseTimeObject in BaseTimeObjects)
            {
                float newValue;
                newValue = BaseTimeObject.Source / Period; // pseudo calculation for generating rsi
                setter(BaseTimeObject, newValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key idea here is setting the property via an Action in the caller. With this solution, the calculation methods are reused for any object and any property with good performance.

Comment: It looks like you need an Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've got the full picture here, but from my understanding, you'll need to have an interface with a base class. The interface is the one that you'll use to define the object, while the base class is the container for all common operations, which can be inhered by the class children. Then, you can create child class (as many as you want) and inherit the base class. The child class will have its required properties, methods, and logic if needed.

Enough talking, let's take it in code :

```
interface ITimeMulti
{
    DateTime DateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    float Source { get; set; }

    // will be used for number of available properties.
    int MultCount { get; } 

    // the main method for generating the multipliers. 
    void Generate(int multNumber, int multiplier); 
}
```

Simple ? let's now create the base class :

```
public class TimeMulti : ITimeMulti
{
    public DateTime DateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    public float Source { get; set; }

    // Using Dictionary will be much faster than Reflection 
    protected static Dictionary<string, float> Multipliers { get; set; }

    // Number of Properties (the set should be within the derived classes)
    public int MultCount { get; protected set; }


    // This is a restriction to create this instance from the derived classes only 
    private TimeMulti() { } 

    // for derived classes 
    protected TimeMulti(int multCount)
    {
        // Should be in this constructor only
        Initiate(multCount);
    }

    // This is the main method to generate the multiplication part. 
    public void Generate(int multNumber, int multiplier)
    {
        if (multNumber == 0)
        {
            Multipliers["Mult"] = Source * multiplier;
        }
        else if (Multipliers.ContainsKey("Mult" + multNumber))
        {
            // store the value in the dictionary (this is for reference)
            Multipliers["Mult" + multNumber] = SetMult(multNumber, Source * multiplier);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }

    }

    // On new instance, this will fired, which will setup the dictionary
    protected void Initiate(int numberOfMultipliers)
    {
        // Ensure you have an active instance of the dictionary
        if (Multipliers == null)
            Multipliers = new Dictionary<string, float>();

        // Ensurance 
        if(numberOfMultipliers > 0)
        {
            MultCount = numberOfMultipliers;

            for (int x = 1; x <= numberOfMultipliers; x++)
                if (!Multipliers.ContainsKey("Mult" + x))
                    Multipliers.Add("Mult" + x, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

    }

    // this is where we will replace Reflection, here is just returning the multValue
    // we will override it on the derived classes 
    protected virtual float SetMult(int MultNumber, float multValue) => multValue;

}
```

Now, the derived class

```
public class Minute : TimeMulti
{
    public float Mult1 { get; set; }
    public float Mult2 { get; set; }
    public float Mult3 { get; set; }
    public float Mult4 { get; set; }

    // MultCount = 4
    public Minute(): base(4) { }

    // This method will set the value of the property using switch statment, with this, you will avoid Reflection. 
    protected override float SetMult(int multNumber, float multValue)
    {
        switch (multNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                Mult1 = multValue;
                break;
            case 2:
                Mult2 = multValue;
                break;
            case 3:
                Mult3 = multValue;
                break;
            case 4:
                Mult4 = multValue;
                break;
        }

        return multValue;
    }   

}
```

Now, you can do this :

```
   class Program
{
    // Create List with type of the ITimeMulti interface
    public static List<ITimeMulti> Minutes = new List<ITimeMulti>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Generate a sample
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
            Minutes.Add(new Minute() { Source = i});

        // Calculate 
        GenerateMultipliers(Minutes, 1, 2); 

    }

    public static void GenerateMultipliers(List<ITimeMulti> source, int multNumber, int multiplier)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            source[i].Generate(multNumber, multiplier);
        }

    }

}
```

If you want to create a new derived class :

```
   public class Day : TimeMulti
    {
        // Properties 
        public float Mult1 { get; set; }

        // Constructor 
        public Day(): base(1) { }

        // This method to map the values to the properties 
        protected override float SetMult(int multNumber, float multValue)
        {
            switch (multNumber)
            {
                case 1:
                    Mult1 = multValue;
                    break;
            }

            return multValue;
        }   

    }
```

This is just an example to give you a new ideas, you can do your own magic. I wouldn't go with `Mult1` ...etc. I would go with a unique and a descriptive names.

**Updated :** 
You can improve the performance of your updated code, by gathering all common properties in the base and make use of `virtual` and `override` if you want to have something override-able in a child class. Or, use `interface` and `struct` instead of classes. Also, instead of using `IEnumerable` use `Array` this would improve your performance as well.

```
public class BaseTime
{
    // shared proprties 
    public DateTime DateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public float Source { get; set; }
    public float MovingAverageFast { get; set; }
    public float MovingAverageSlow { get; set; }
    public float RsiFast { get; set; }
    public float RsiSlow { get; set; }

}

public class Minute : BaseTime
{
    // add your custom code for Minute
    // No need for recreating them, since it's already inherited from the base 
}

public class Day : BaseTime
{
    // add your custom code for Day
    // No need for recreating them, since it's already inherited from the base 
}

class Program
{
    public static BaseTime[] Minutes;

    public static BaseTime[] Days;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Minutes = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).Select(n => (BaseTime) new Minute { Source = n }).ToArray();
        Days = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).Select(n => (BaseTime) new Day { Source = n }).ToArray();

        // Generating data for Minutes
        GenerateMovingAverage(Minutes, 100, (m, value) => m.MovingAverageFast = value);
        GenerateRsi(Minutes, 60, (m, value)  => m.RsiFast = value);
        GenerateRsi(Minutes, 250, (m, value) => m.RsiSlow = value);

        // Generating data for Days
        GenerateMovingAverage(Days, 8, (d, value)  => d.MovingAverageFast = value);
        GenerateMovingAverage(Days, 45, (d, value) => d.MovingAverageSlow = value);
        GenerateRsi(Days, 5, (d, value)  => d.RsiFast = value);
        GenerateRsi(Days, 21, (d, value) => d.RsiSlow = value);         
    }

    public static void GenerateMovingAverage(BaseTime[] BaseTimeObjects, int Period, Action<BaseTime, float> setter) 
    {
        foreach (var BaseTimeObject in BaseTimeObjects)
        {
            setter(BaseTimeObject, BaseTimeObject.Source * Period);
        }
    }

    public static void GenerateRsi(BaseTime[] BaseTimeObjects, int Period, Action<BaseTime, float> setter)
    {
        foreach (var BaseTimeObject in BaseTimeObjects)
        {
            setter(BaseTimeObject, BaseTimeObject.Source / Period);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it looks a bit long-winded, especially with 100 properties. Also, the performance isn't too good. See my post for an updated solution.

Comment: @jrw as I said, it's not clear your requirements, but at least you'll have something different in your hand to play with. I have updated my answer with your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @iSR5 wrote, you might consider using a [factory design pattern](https://www.binpress.com/factory-design-pattern/), making classes that do the actual calculations. This would be good if you don't know what you actually need to do until run time.

```
public interface IMultiValueGenerator
{
  void GenerateValue(ITimeMulti multi, int multiplier);
}

public class Multi2Generator : IMultiValueGenerator
{
  public void GenerateValue(ITimeMulti multi, int multiplier)
  {
    multi.Mult2 = multi.Source * multiplier;
  }
}

public static class MultiGeneratorFactory
{
   public static IMultiValueGenerator GetGenerator(...)
   {
      if (condition)
        return new Multi2Generator();
      // etc
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It allowed me to understand how the factory design pattern works. However, it seems to me that this will necessitate a calculation method for every property. See my post for an updated solution.